# Add style on every third entry

Tags: templating

Trying to add entries in a visual array on my homepage.
Problem is that I need a special class on the last item in every row.
*col_last*

Trying to get my head around how to automate this, in order to avoid "special entries" for these.

Any ideas?

```
{% for item in craft.entries.section('services').orderBy('postDate asc').all() %}
    <div class="clear bottommargin-sm"></div>
    <div class="col_one_third *col_last*">
        <div class="feature-box fbox-small fbox-plain" data-animate="fadeIn">
            <div class="fbox-icon">
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-{{ item.serviceIcon }}"></i></a>
            </div>
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ item.serviceTagline }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you really need a special class or just a special style (css)?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to ADD a class, but I guess it pretty much the same procedure to single out every 3'rd item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `cycle` your `loop.index0` property if you really need to add a class

```
{{ cycle(['first', 'second', 'last'], loop.index0) }}
```

If the other elements don't need a class insert an empty value `''`

You can as well check for a specific value of your `loop.index0`

However if you just want to add certain style attributes you can use the [nth](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) selector

Comment: THAT worked like a charm!
THANKS!